# Morera's theorem application

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

How can I use Morera's theorem to prove that
$$ f(z) = \int_0^1 t^z d\mu (t) $$ 
is a holomorphic function on the right half plane $\{Re(z)>0\}$, given $t\in(0,1)$ and being $\mu$ a complex Borel measure concentrated on $(0,1]$ ?

This comes from Rudin's proof of the Müntz-Szasz theorem.

Comment: Take a triangle $\Delta$ in the right half plane, and use Fubini. You can also differentiate under the integral and check the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: So I just have to do this
$$\int_{dΔ} \int_0^1 t^z d\mu(z) = $$
$$\int_0^1 (\int_{dΔ} t^z) d\mu(z) = 0$$

and I can do it because $f(z)$ is continuous, right?

Comment: Right. Except for the notational error, it's $\partial \Delta$, not $d\Delta$ ;)

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't remember the correct LaTeX command.

One more thing: is the condition "$\mu$ is concentrated on $(0,1]$ " necessary? What do I lose if I use a $\mu$ not concentrated on that? I looked up properties of complex Borel measures but I found nothing

Comment: If $\mu(\{0\}) \neq 0$, you have to deal with the problem that $0^z$ isn't automatically defined. Not a big deal, but avoiding it makes the proof a little shorter.